# How to calculate percentile-like mean, does it even have a real mathematical name?

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, mean, percentile

Let *S={s<sub>0</sub>, s<sub>1</sub>, ..., s<sub>n</sub>}* and *s<sub>i</sub>* ∈ **R**

Median *m* of set *S* is also known as a 50-percentile because:

50% * card(*s<sub>i</sub>* < m) = 50% * card(*s<sub>i</sub>* > m)

If *m* is *α*-percentile then:

(100% - *α*) * card(*s<sub>i</sub>* < m)) = *α* * card(*s<sub>i</sub>* > m)

Assuming we want simmilar behaviour from mean we can say that:
Mean *m* of set *S* is also known as a 50-percentile-like-mean because:

50% * sum<sup>*n*</sup><sub>*i=0, s<sub>i</sub> < m*</sub> ( *m* - *s<sub>i</sub>* ) = 50% * sum<sup>*n*</sup><sub>*i=0, s<sub>i</sub> > m*</sub> ( *m* - *s<sub>i</sub>* )

Then we can define *α*-percentile-like-mean to be:

(100% - *α*) * sum<sup>*n*</sup><sub>*i=0, s<sub>i</sub> < m*</sub> ( *m* - *s<sub>i</sub>* ) = *α* * sum<sup>*n*</sup><sub>*i=0, s<sub>i</sub> > m*</sub> ( *m* - *s<sub>i</sub>* )

My questions are:

1. Does percentile-like-mean have a real mathematical name ?
2. Can this equation be solved (find *m* for some given set *S*) in a linear time (like mean) ?
3. If not can this be solved using something faster than binary search for *m* (card(S) ~= 10<sup>7</sup>) ?

I have only managed to come up with binary search:
Let *a,b = min(S), max(S)*, let *m* = a=b/2, naively calculate both sides of the equation and adjust *a=m* or *b=m* depending on which side was greater.

Maybe the the binary search can be further optimised ? Like spliting range a-b with *α* and 1-*α* instead 50%-50%, or using the difference between both sides of the equation somehow ?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your definition on the percentile-like-mean: one side is always negative, the other is always positive.
To fix that you need to negate one of the sides:

(1 - *α*) Σ<sub>*s<sub>i</sub><m*</sub> (*m* - *s<sub>i</sub>*) = *α* Σ<sub>*s<sub>i</sub>>=m*</sub> (*s<sub>i</sub>* - *m*)

Then it can be verified that it is equivalent with the arithmetic mean for α = 50%. I also include the *s<sub>i</sub>* = *m* in the sum; this doesn't change the definition, but simplifies the math.

The above equation can be rewritten as:

*m* =
((1 - *α*) Σ<sub>*s<sub>i</sub><m*</sub> *s<sub>i</sub>* + *α* Σ<sub>*s<sub>i</sub>>=m*</sub> *s<sub>i</sub>*) / ((1 - *α*) Σ<sub>*s<sub>i</sub><m*</sub> 1 + *α* Σ<sub>*s<sub>i</sub>>=m*</sub> 1)

Assuming that *s<sub>i</sub>* are sorted and *s<sub>j</sub> <= m < s<sub>j+1</sub>* for some *j*, it can be rewritten as:

*m* =
((1 - *α*) Σ<sub>*i<j*</sub> *s<sub>i</sub>* + *α* Σ<sub>*i*>=*j*</sub> *s<sub>i</sub>*) / ((1 - *α*) *j* + *α* (*n - j*))

What's left is to check if any *j* solves the equation, which can be done in linear time by maintaining the partial sums on the left and on the right:

```
double left = 0, right = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    right += s[i];

for(int j = 0; j+1 < n; ++j) {
    left += s[j];
    right -= s[j];
    double m = ((1-a)*left + a*right)/((1-a)*(j+1) + a*(n-j-1));
    if(s[j] <= m && m < s[j+1])
        return m;
}
```

Comment: If you have coded the solution, have you found instances where there is no solution or many solutions?

Comment: @SimonGoater thinking about it, as m increases from min(si) to max(si), the LHS of the definition monotonically and continuously increases from 0 to a positive number, the RHS monotonically and continuously decreases from some positive number to 0. Thus they must intersect at some unique m. That's under reasonable assumptions that 0 < alpha < 1 and si aren't all equal. The code seems to work but may have some bugs though.

Comment: You're using continuity in your argument, but this is a discrete problem as j, in your example, must be an integer and m is a function of j. I'm not sure there must be one and only one qualifying j.

Comment: @SimonGoater my argument is based directly on the 1st equation, which doesn't have j in it. LHS and RHS are both continuous and monotonous functions of the real m. You may be thinking that there's a discontinuity when a new term appears in the sum, but that's not the case because when it happens, then (m = si) and the term starts from zero, maintaining the continuity. Can also write it as (1 - α) Σ max(m - si,0) = α Σ max(si - m,0) so that all the terms are there, non-negative, monotonic, and continuous.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your definition a bit because of Yakov Galka's observations.

```
(100 - a) * sum_{s_i < m} (m - s_i) = a * sum_{s_i > m} (s_i - m)
```

This can be rearranged as follows,...

```
m((100 - a) * count_{s_i < m} + a * count_{s_i > m}) = (a * sum_{s_i > m} s_i) + ((100 - a) * sum_{s_i < m} s_i)
```

If the s_i are sorted in ascending order, then making a guess for count_{s_i < m} makes it easy to calculate m. It makes more sense to me to do an integer binary search on count_{s_i < m} to find a value of m that satisfies the equation. It isn't clear to me at this time that a solution will always exist or that a solution would be unique.  I think this approach would be O(nlogn) so should be achievable in a reasonable time even if n approx 10^7.